# Octagon inside a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

An octagon which has side lengths 3, 3, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15 and 15  is inscribed
in a circle. What is the area of the octagon?

I tried using the cosine law on the triangles made when connected with the center but the numbers became really hard to use when I solved for the sine of the angles to easily get the triangle area.

This is a problem from BIMC 2017 individual question 6, where the answer is 567. ;)

Comment: Are those side lengths in order?

Comment: @Arthur I don't think it matters.  For a given radius, the area of the triangles depends only on the sides.  But since the central angles have to add up to $2\pi,$ you should be able to solve for the radius.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  So far, I can't see any way to do it except numerically.  Is there reason to believe it has some clever exact solution?

Comment: Given that the order does not matter, I'd put them in the order $3, 15, 11, 15, 3, 15, 11, 15$. The symmetry not only makes opposite sides parallel, the sides of length $3$ will be perpendicular to the sides of length $11$. That has to help a lot.

Comment: This problem from BIMC 2017 individual question 6 where the answer is 567 ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inscribed irregular octagon area](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2705522/557074)

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Arranging the sides in the order $3,15,11,15,3,15,11,15$, we obtain two overlapping, perpendicular inscribed rectangles of sides $3×h$ and $11×k$ respectively, where $h,k$ are to be determined. The Pythagorean theorem gives
$$3^2+h^2=11^2+k^2$$
$$h^2-k^2=112$$
Furthermore, the rectangles are aligned and have a common centroid. This gives
$$\left(\frac{h-11}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{k-3}2\right)^2=15^2$$
$$(h-11)^2+(k-3)^2=30^2$$
This immediately suggests finding Pythagorean triples $(a,b,30)$, of which there is only one: $18^2+24^2=30^2$. If we let $h-11=18$ and $k-3=24$, we see that the other equation $h^2-k^2=112$ is "miraculously" satisfied.

Thus $h=29$ and $k=27$. The octagon's area can then be calculated easily by adding the rectangles' areas, subtracting their intersection and adding the triangles' areas:
$$3h+11k-33+2\left(\frac{h-11}2\right)\left(\frac{k-3}2\right)=87+297-33+2\cdot9\cdot12=567$$

Comment: I've neatened up your figure with Geogebra, if you'd like https://i.imgur.com/ztpQFxc.png

Comment: @Jam one of the traditions I've had with my answers here is hand-drawn diagrams, particularly because I answer most questions on my mobile phone. But a neat diagram is always good to have.

Answer (score 2):

Arrange the triangles so there is a $15$ in each quadrant; the $3$ sides are vertical and the $11$ sides are horizontal.  Then the distance between $(\sqrt{r^2-9/4},3/2)$ and $(11/2,\sqrt{r^2-121/4})$ is 15.